# Missing debug tab in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

first question here. Hope it goes well...

I'm novice in Android Studio, but used to have the debug tab and now I can't find it back (after collapsing it. I do have the logcat and monitors tab though... See printscreen.
(As you can see, I don't have a small icon on the right top side of the window to click and reveal the debug tab, as is referred to as a solution in another thread.)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjEfh.png)

What I'm looking for (such that I can debug line per line):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBILP.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The screenshots show two different windows. One is Android Monitor. The other is Debug. You can see this difference in the gray bar above the tabs. Both have a logcat tab but differ significantly beyond that.

The quickest way to get the Debug window is to set a breakpoint and click the debug button on the toolbar. You can also go to the View menu or click the button in the lower left corner to view the Debug window.

Answer (score 7):

Press Alt+5 to show the debug window

Comment: could this become a comment for the actual answer?

Comment: Well.. it could, but:

"Comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post. Outdated comments may get deleted."

As I understand, I'm posting the solution for the question.

Comment: Command + 5 on Mac for those that are wondering.